# 2010 - Email a selection from a datasheet

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-part, workflow, alert, rss

Environment: 2010 Enterprise

One of our sites has several lists created from uploading spreadsheets and viewing them in a datasheet view. Some users have been asking if there's a way to easily select a range of cells in the datasheet and send them to someone else on the fly (without copying them into an Excel document, saving it, and sending it as an email attachment). I feel like this shouldn't be too difficult to accomplish, but I don't know exactly how to approach it. Is there a way to do this with something like a content query web part, or a relatively simple workflow?

It doesn't necessarily have to be emailed directly, if there's a way to use RSS feeds, built-in web parts, or alerts to accomplish this it would be just as good.

Any advice or a push in the right direction to figure it out would be greatly appreciated!

**Update:** They have informed me that they would be sending whole rows (minus some columns with sensitive information, which is easy enough to filter out), not just random selections, so that could make things easier.

Comment: Am I right in assuming you need to do this because the desired recipients do not have access to the sharepoint site? Is there metadata in place to "filter" out the items which you wish to email?

Comment: That's correct, they just want to send selected parts of the tables as those specific items are updated. At the moment there are no filters in place, but there's plenty of metadata to use in them if necessary.